# Javascript DOM Trickiness

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to go about self-referencing a table row in Javascript.

Here's the boiled down code:

```
$( "#listitems tbody" ).append( "<tr onclick=\"editListItem(this)\">" +
        "<td>" + id.val() + "</td>" +  
        "<td>" + title.val() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + description.val() + "</td>" + 
        "<td>" + TF + "</td>" + 
        "<td style=\"visibility: hidden;\">" + id.val() + "</td>" + 
"</tr>" );
```

As you can see, I'm setting the contents of this table row and cells dynamically. However, I need to pass a reference to this table row into its onClick function, which calls this Javascript method:

```
function editListItem(obj) {
    var id = obj.cells[4].innerHTML;
    var cells = document.getElementById('listitems').rows[id].cells;
    DATA[0] = cells[0].innerHTML;
    DATA[1] = cells[1].innerHTML;
    DATA[2] = cells[2].innerHTML;
    DATA[3] = cells[3].innerHTML;
}
```

In this method, I need to access the value contained *inside* the 4th "hidden" cell of the table row that was clicked. I normally would just pass the ID variable into the onClick method, but this table's contents can be sorted and rearranged, so the ID variable will not necessarily correspond to the contents of the row.

I've been Googling for the past four hours but can't find any specific examples for this situation; everything I've tried just triggers a Javascript error proclaiming that obj.cells, obj[4], obj.childNodes, etc, does not exist, depending on which one I'm trying.

Does anyone know how you can access the innerHTML of table cell elements inside a table row element by passing "this" into the table row's onClick?

Please let me know if any part of this was confusing, I'm trying to get this done before I leave today or I know I'll forget it all and have to start all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your code, your using jQuery so you can easily grab the 5th td by using

```
$(this).children('td').eq(4)
```

and then do whatever you want with that jQuery element

checkout [jQuery eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) for more info

Comment: You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar, although instead of "this", I had to use the "obj" parameter I passed, since a simple inline onClick does not properly register possession of the function, it's only a function call. I had to pass a "this" reference into the event handler and access it via $(obj) instead of implicitly using $(this). Thanks! :)

Comment: good catch, although in best practice, you should avoid inlining your events and register them on the dom element in javascript

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
$( "#listitems tbody" ).append(
    $('<tr>....</tr>')
        .bind('click', function(){
            var tds = $(this).find('td'),
                 id = tds.eq(4).text();
        })
);
```

And if that's not what you meant, let me know.  I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking for :)

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't know what syntax to use to actually reference the subelements of the row; I believe using a bind is the same as passing "this" into the onClick method, correct me if I'm wrong. A.k.a., if "this" is the table row, how do I actually reference its cells? this.cells doesn't seem to work, nor this.childNodes, nor directly using this[#].

Answer (score 1):

Create your `<tr>` element on its own first, and use proper JS to register the handler rather than embedding the handler in the element's attributes:

```
var tr = $('<tr>').click(editListItem);
$("#listitems tbody").append(tr);
$(tr).append( ... );
```

In `editListItem`, `this` will automatically apply to the whole row element:

```
function editListItem(row) {
    var cells = $(this).children('td');
    var id = $cells.eq(4).text();
    var data = [];
    data[0] = cells.eq(0).html();
}
```

Comment: Close, although I don't see why registering the handler makes any difference versus embedding the handler; the "this" reference should still apply in both cases as long as the table row has possession of the event handler, right? Anyway, I ran into some issues with your solution, but thanks for the help! :)